# Почему readLine() не принимает данные

Tags: java, android, сокет, передача-данных

У меня есть код для отправки данных:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                                                            try {
                                                                out.write(finalI + "&" + finalJ+" \n");
                                                                out.flush();
                                                            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                                                            }
                                                            return null;
                                                        }
                                                    }.execute();
```

И код который принимает данные:

```
                                        @Override
                                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                                        try {
                                            out.write(finalI+"&"+finalJ+"\n");
                                            out.flush();
                                           if(pole_two_comps==0){
                                               while(true){
                                            String readLines = in.readLine();
                                            if(readLines!=null){
                                                readLine=readLines;
                                            break;
                                            }
                                               }
                                           }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    }
```

Но данные не передаются.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить этот код  чтобы он начал работать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120028/discussion-on-question-by-java-js-html-css--readline---).

Comment: У меня не работает этот чат

Comment: что именно не работает? Достаточно просто залогиниться

Comment: Ну я залогинился, и там сообщение "надо набрать 20 баллов репутации"

Comment: у тебя хватает репутации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде `out.flush();` была ошибка "Broken pipe"